# Selecting words that end in 'n' in oracle sqlplus

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Select first names and last names of the table teachers where first names end in 'n'.

I wrote:

```
select first_name, last_name 
from teachers 
where type='teacher' 
and last_name like '%n';
```

Unfortunately it selects no rows. It should select at least two.

The problem is with " last_name like '%n' " and I can't find a solution. Does anyone have any idea how i can solve this?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVE3Z.png)

Comment: Provide the Data which you are expecting will be returned by your query.  Column values..

Comment: The query should work. So it must be your data. Perhaps the `first_name` (or `type`?) are in upper-case. Or perhaps `first_name` contains trailing spaces, or some other non-printing character. If you can't figure it out for yourself you'll need to post some sample data which reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include examples of the data you're working with. Thanks.

Comment: In your sample  (in Screenshot )  you have not 'Teacher'  with firts_name that end  with 'n'

Comment: I updated with a screenshot of my work.

Comment: From the screenshoot it appears the type is `'Teacher'`, not `'teacher'` as in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, in your example there are no `first_name` columns that end with `n`. Yep.

Why? The the column type of `first_name` is `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR2`, so Oracle fills up the column with spaces when each first name is shorter than 10 characters.

Solutions?

1. Use `VARCHAR2` instead of `CHAR` as in:

   ```
   create table teacher (
     last_name varchar2(10), -- VARCHAR2 now!
     first_name varchar2(10), -- VARCHAR2 now!
     type varchar2(10)
   );
   ```

   With this structure your query will run well.
2. Alternatively, if you don't want to change the table structure, you can `TRIM()` the column, as in:

   ```
   select first_name, last_name 
   from teachers 
   where type='teacher' 
   and trim(first_name) like '%n'; -- use TRIM here!
   ```

Comment: I tried with trim(), didn't work. I will try to change to varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using. This will eliminate the chances of leftout of Case sensitive Data.

```
select first_name, last_name from teachers where lower(type)='teacher' and lower(first_name ) like '%n';
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said, still not working. I added a screenshot in the main post..

Answer (score 0):

As you were told, your query *should* work. Problem is probably trivial (does case matters? Are there really lower case "n" letters in those names?).

Meanwhile, a few options for you:

```
SQL> select ename from emp
  2  where ename like '%N';

ENAME
----------
ALLEN
MARTIN

SQL> select ename from emp
  2  where substr(ename, -1) = 'N';

ENAME
----------
ALLEN
MARTIN

SQL> select ename from emp
  2  where regexp_like(ename, 'N$');

ENAME
----------
ALLEN
MARTIN

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: CHAR datatype issue]**

```
SQL> create table empc (ename char(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into empc select ename from emp;

12 rows created.

SQL> select ename from empc where ename like '%N';

no rows selected

SQL> select ename from empc where trim(ename) like '%N';

ENAME
----------
ALLEN
MARTIN

SQL>
```

Comment: I added a screenshot with the table and its content in the main post, it's still not working.

Comment: Cause of the problem is column's datatype - CHAR is right-padded with spaces, up to column's full length. For example, if it is CHAR(10) and you put 'Mike' in there, it'll be stored as `Mike      `. You should TRIM column. Or, switch to VARCHAR2 (which is a preferred solution). I've edited my answer, just to show what happens with CHARs.

Answer (score 0):

as per the screenshot the first_name, last_name columns have datatype as CHAR.
the thing about CHAR is that is appends spaces to reach its full length.
Example: for first_name CHAR(10) if u store 'Andra' it will be stored as 'Andra     '

so use the trim function:

```
select first_name, last_name 
from teachers 
where type='teacher' 
and trim(first_name) like '%n';
```

alternatively use the VARCHAR2 datatype instead of CHAR.
it does not append spaces at the end to reach its full length.

Answer (score 0):

If you have char data  type then you should try trimming  of space chars from your first_name values

```
select first_name, last_name 
from teachers 
where type='teacher' 
and trim(first_name)  like '%n';
```

anyway  in your screeshot  you have not teacher  with firt_name endig with  `n` ..try

```
select first_name, last_name 
from teachers 
where trim(first_name)  like '%n';
```

Comment: Trim doesn't work. I will try to change the type to varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like
`SELECT *
  FROM teachers a
 WHERE TRIM (LOWER (a.first_name)) LIKE '%n';`